# Adding multiple sprites dynamically

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

Want to add sprites dynamically using a for loop as a newbie to cocos2d i cant figure out this issue so please help me out of this situation

here is my code..

```
rock = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Rock.png"];
        [rock setPosition:ccp(240,80)];
        [self addChild:rock];
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {            
            rock2 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Rock.png"];
            [rock2 setPosition:ccp(rock.position.x-70,rock.position.y+40)];
            [self addChild:rock2];
        }
```

thanks in advance..

Comment: what out put you getting? 3 sprites from for loop will overlap

Comment: currently displaying only 2 sprites

Comment: how you want the out put? 3 sprite in a line behind rock?

Comment: 2nd sprite at position cpp(170,120) i am getting this one correct 3rd sprite must be at position cpp(100,160)and fourth one at cpp(30,200)i cant manage to get last two ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
int xpos, ypos;
xpos = 70;
ypos = 40;
rock = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Rock.png"];
        [rock setPosition:ccp(240,80)];
        [self addChild:rock];
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {            
            rock2 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Rock.png"];
            [rock2 setPosition:ccp(rock.position.x-xpos,rock.position.y+ypos)];
            [self addChild:rock2];
            xpos = xpos + 70;
            ypos = ypos + 40; 
        }
```

change xpos and ypos as you need

Answer (score 0):

whats the issue?

It will generate total 4 sprites . visually you will be able to see two sprites because 3 of the sprites are exactly at the same position.

Comment: make sure their positions vary...........all the sprites you are creating in a loop are exactly at same position

Answer (score 0):

You're not changing the position of the rocks you're adding in the loop resulting in 3 rocks in the same place.

Comment: for the first iteration i can set the position with respect to "rock" which creates "rock2(1)" now how can i set position with respect to this created rock????